# "mongo" working but "mongod" not working [MacOS][Mongo]

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, installation, cmd, macos-catalina

I am trying to run a command:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath </path/to/your/data/folder/> --maxConns 75
```

where `</path/to/your/data/folder/>` is the path to my data folder, It shows following error:

```
sudo: mongod: command not found
```

In my MacOS terminal `mongo` cmd is **working** fine the mongo terminal opens when i run it, but `mongod` command is **not working**.
When I try to run `mongod` it shows:

```
zsh: command not found: mongod
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run the below-mentioned `cmds` and it somehow worked:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@4.4
```